# Instead of the key clock login page, how can I build my own login page?

Tags: authentication, spring-security, authorization, keycloak

I have a service with multiple domains.
And I want to implement Sso in this service.
I tried to implement it using keycloak
I want to create a new login page with react instead of the login page of Key Clock. And I am thinking of implementing a spring security server separately to add an email or sms 2factor function.

In order to do that, I think I should use keycloak rest api.
But the problem is that I don't know how the key clock login page authenticates the user.

Can I know the login flow of the key clock in detail?

For example, if I want to check if Service 1 is logged in, do I need to redirect to the login page of Key Clock to check the cookie or session ID of the login page?
So how do I know if I'm constantly logged in?

Comment: It looks like Keycloak has built-in [support](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_themes) for customizing the login page. This approach would likely be more maintainable than creating a new login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keycloak already provides a way to edit Login flow. You can also add more fields etc. to the Login Form and add 2 factor authentication as well. The only thing is, you will have to use `Freemarker` for the same.

 See, https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#implementing-an-authenticator and https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_themes